# What is the best method to validate the e-mail address in Azure AD B2C custom policy to restrict the particular domain name?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a requirement to restrict a domain (assume gmail.com) not be used by user during the sign-up flow. For the email address validation, we used regular expression in custom policy.

```
<ClaimType Id="email">
        <Restriction>
      <Pattern RegularExpression="^(?![a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~\-]+@(gmail.com))" HelpText="Please enter an allowed email address." />
        </Restriction>
```

But when user try to enter something example@GmaiL.Com the validation fails during the email verification step, because the regular expression is not case-insensitive. Please suggest a better approach to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some workaround with multiple technical profiles.

1. Technical profile to trigger the "ChangeCase" claim transform, to transform e-mail address to lowercase.

   ```
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="ChangeToLower" 
    TransformationMethod="ChangeCase">
    <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" 
    TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="toCase" DataType="string" Value="LOWER"/>
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" 
     TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
     </OutputClaims>
     </ClaimsTransformation>
   ```

Technical Profile

```
    <TechnicalProfiles>
     <TechnicalProfile Id="TP-ChangeEmailCaseToLower">
    <DisplayName>Check Company validity </DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
     </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ChangeToLower"/>
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

2. Technical profile to trigger the "ParseDomain" claim transform.

   ```
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="SetDomainName" 
    TransformationMethod="ParseDomain">
    <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" 
    TransformationClaimType="emailAddress" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainName" 
    TransformationClaimType="domain" />
    </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>

     <TechnicalProfile Id="TP-ParseDomianName">
      <DisplayName>Unit test</DisplayName>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
     </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetDomainName" 
        />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
3. Comparing the domainName Claim to value "gmail.com"

   ```
   <ClaimsTransformation Id="CompareEmailCalimToValue" 
    TransformationMethod="CompareClaimToValue">
    <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainName" 
     TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
    </InputClaims>
     <InputParameters>
     <InputParameter Id="compareTo" DataType="string" 
      Value="gmail.com" />
     <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="not 
     equal" />
    <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" 
      />
   ```

   ```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="TP-ParseDomianNameClaimCheck">
      <DisplayName>Unit test</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" 
    Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainName"/>
     </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isDomainMatches"/>          
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CompareEmailCalimToValue" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
4. Assert BooleanClaim(isDomainMatches) IsEqual To Value

   ```
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertEmailDomainIsTrue" 
    TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
    <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isDomainMatches" 
     TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" 
     Value="true" />
    </InputParameters>
   </ClaimsTransformation>



      <TechnicalProfile Id="Example-AssertBoolean">
    <DisplayName>Unit test</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ComparisonResult" DefaultValue="false"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailDomainIsTrue" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
   ```

Using the ValidationTechnicalProfile

```
   <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">The Montgomery County work E-Address are not accepted.</Item>
          </Metadata>
     ..........
           <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TP-ChangeEmailCaseToLower" ContinueOnError="false"/>
         <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TP-ParseDomianName" ContinueOnError="false" />
          <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TP-ParseDomianNameClaimCheck" ContinueOnError="false"/>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Example-AssertBoolean" ContinueOnError="false"/>
     
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" >        
       </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
         </TechnicalProfile>
```